# Postgres encode() function doesn't work with a function as an argument

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm trying to use Postgresql encode() function and put some other functions as it's arguments. I get errors, and I can't understand why.

I am using Postgres 9.6.14 on Windows.

1. This works fine and returns `698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668`

```sql
select md5('111');
```

2. This also works fine and returns some value

```sql
select encode('698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668', 'base64');
```

3. But this one, which combines the first 2, doesn't work and returns `"ERROR: function encode(text, unknown) does not exist"`

```sql
select encode(md5('111'), 'base64');
```

4. This also doesn't work and returns the same error

```sql
select encode(concat('1', '11'), 'base64');
```

5. I thought that there is a rule which prevents to use one function inside another, but the following one works fine and returns the same value as the first request here, as expected.

```sql
select md5(concat('1', '11'))
```

So what's the issue with requests number 3 and 4 and `encode()` function overall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definition of `encode`:

```
\df encode
                          List of functions
   Schema   |  Name  | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
------------+--------+------------------+---------------------+------
 pg_catalog | encode | text             | bytea, text         | func
(1 row)
```

The first argument has to be `bytea`, that is a binary byte string.

Your first two queries work because string literals are of type `unknown`, which can be cast to `bytea` implicitly.

In the queries that do not work, you are using the functions `md5` and `concat`, which both have `text` as a result type. Now there is no implicit cast between `text` and `bytea`, hence the error message.

To make that work, you have to introduce an explicit type cast:

```
select encode(CAST(md5('111') AS bytea), 'base64');
```

Comment: Though if your aim is to get the base64 representation of the MD5 hash, you probably want `encode(CAST('\x' || md5('111') AS bytea), 'base64')` instead